# Using אוהביו, יראיו, חסידיו in Chovas Halevavos referring to those who receive additional reward

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, reward-punishment, chovos-halvavos

ספר חובות הלבבות - שער הביטחון - פרק רביעי

Chovos Halevavos (Duties of the Heart) [Shaar Habitachon](https://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=380#ch4) (Gate of Trust) Chapter 4:

> ועניני העולם הבא יחלקו לשני חלקים ... והשני שהוא מחסד הבורא יתעלה **על החסידים והנביאים** לעולם הבא.
>
> Matters of the afterlife subdivide into two parts...
>
> And the second: That which is a special kindness which the Creator bestows **to the pious and to the prophets** in Olam Haba.

> והנה כל הדברים שבוטחים בהם הבורא יתברך שבעה חלקים: אחד... והשביעי גמול העולם הבא אשר יהיה מהבורא יתברך על דרך החסד **על סגולתו ואוהביו**, כמו שכתוב (תהלים לא, כ) מה רב טובך אשר צפנת **ליראיך** פעלת לחוסים בך נגד בני אדם:
>
> Thus all things for which one trusts in the Creator fall into 7 categories:
>   (1)... (7) reward in the afterlife from the Creator in the way of kindness **on His treasured ones and those who love Him** (i.e. to increase their reward due to their love and clinging to G-d), as written "How great is Your goodness that You have hidden away **for those who fear You**; You have done for those who trust in You before the sons of men!" (Tehillim 31:20):

QUESTION:

In the first part, he says that the additional reward (besides that which is accorded for one's actions) is designated to החסידים והנביאים - the pious and to the prophets, Then in the second part he repeats this but writes that it is designated for  סגולתו ואוהביו - His treasured ones and those who love Him, and then he brings a passuk as a source for this which says "אשר צפנת ליראיך" - which You have hidden away for "those who fear You".

So who gets this additional reward? The pious and prophets, the treasured ones, and those who love Him, or those who fear Him?

Comment: The tradition (I keep so) about Sifreri Musar that they never use exact wording as they never use exact definitions.  For a Musar book, referring to pious Jews can be all of the above - אוהביו, יראיו, חסידיו etc. But I +1 it as it is a good question to be asked legitimately.

Comment: By the way, this "mess" is consistent with Tehillim themselves, where KD uses tens of different expressions to refer to שומרי המצוות.

Comment: @AlBerko That's because Tehillim is *kisvei Hakodesh*, which has many many depths of understanding for every word used, but why would the CH do that?

Comment: As long as it is not interpreted, I assume they all use the adjectives interchangeably. If you flip a coin, I'm sure HaKB"H has a reason why it falls on tails, but for me it is arbitrary. CH is a lesser, but also [kinda] prophet, why not. I am sure if you were asking him he would say "It just came out of my mouth".

Comment: Did you ever write Chiddushim? Did you re-read it and ask yourself - is it clear enough? Have I used the right words? Suddenly you have no idea why that was the exact wording you've chosen. That's happenning to everyone from KD thru Rambam and Hamechaber ans CH to you. (THis is my private and unsourced opinion. sorry).